# how to assign value of user_id from users table in cart in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to assign id from Users table as user_id for cart and I want to use many to many relationship this is what I did:

```
 public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

```
public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
```

next I don't know what should I do:)

can anyone help me in it?

Comment: can you elaborate a little more .. What you actually want and Give the table structure

Comment: I want to get id from my user table and use it for store,download page etc.actully I want this for user profile and I think it's good to use many to many relationship but I dont know how to use it here

Comment: Do you have a Cart model ?? Where you want to map the User model

Comment: yup,now cart is work but I wanna add user_id too

Answer (score 0):

Within the migration file for creating your cart database table you'll need the lines:

```
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Usually, the relationship between user and cart is one to many, not many to many.

So then, within your user model you'd have:

```
public function carts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cart');
}
```

Within your cart model you'd have:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: and in addToCart method I should have $user_id = Auth::user()->id , right?

Comment: yep or u can use $user_id = Auth::user()->getUserIdentifier;

Comment: @hadis Is this a site where the user has to be logged in before they can add anything to the cart, I only ask because often the cart is just associated with a session and only gets associated with a user when it's converted to an order. Your syntax for getting the logged in user id is correct though, and you can also use Auth::id()

Comment: no actully it's not neccery for user to login for adding to cart but for convert an order it's neccery to login.